# C++ srand seed isn't generating the proper numbers

Tags: c++

For the program I'm working on, we have a function that acts as a dice, generating a random number between 1 and 6. For debugging purposes, the seed we're supposed to use is srand(333), which should give us the same rolls. The first 25 rolls of this seed are supposed to be:

5 4 4 3 3 4 5 2 3 6 5 2 4 1 5 5 3 3 6 4 4 3 4 2 6

However, that definitely isn't happening and I've confirmed that the first three rolls are 5, 5, and 4. The overall program is supposed to simulate a turn of a game of pig, but I feel like the problem has to originate within one of these two functions, and not the main function.

```
int genRandInt (int minroll, int maxroll) {
    int randnum = minroll + (rand() % (maxroll - minroll + 1));
    return randnum;
}
```

or

```
int singleTurn (int holdnum) {
    int diceroll = genRandInt(1,6);
    int score = 0;

    while (score < holdnum) {
        if (diceroll == 1) {
            score = 0;
            return score;
        }
        else {
            score = score + diceroll;
        }
    }
    return score;
}
```

If the main function is also necessary I can post it.

Comment: The first 25 rolls depends on your library version.  What library are you using?  If you don't know, what compiler and version?

Comment: @Mooing Duck I did `#include <cstdlib>` if that's what you mean. One of us is running Code::Blocks 13.12 and the other is running c9, both seem to be getting the same results.

Comment: Under Project/Build options, what compiler is selected to be used?  I don't actually know what Code::Blocks does by default..

Comment: You can't guarantee what sequence any given seed will produce, its it's implementation dependant. All you can know is for a given implementation the same seed will produce the same sequence.

Comment: Aha, Cloud9 apparently uses the libstdc++ implementation of the C++ library, so most likely the Code::BLocks is also using that, whatever the compiler. (yes: GNU GCC Compiler uses libstdC++ as well)

Comment: How do you know The first 25 rolls of this seed?  Did a professor tell you that?  What C++ library is _his_ compiler using?

Comment: @MooingDuck GNU GCC Compiler

Comment: @MooingDuck The first 25 rolls were listed within the assignment.

Comment: I can't find any evidence that rand/srand is defined to produce any particular sequence. The only thing you know is any particular implementation will produce repeatable results.

Comment: the only REAL way to do this would be to write your own random number generator.

Comment: @Rentsy good luck with that

Comment: @vsoftco `#include <stdint.h>  static uint64_t rand64 = 2395040858963409;  static uint64_t add = 1442695040888963407; uint64_t mult = 6364136223846793005; static uint64_t MAXINT_U64 = 18446744073709551615U; double random64() { rand64 = mult * rand64 + add; return (double) rand64/ MAXINT_U64;  }`

Comment: @Rentsy This is a pseudo-random generator, not a random number generator, and if you want to use such thing in serious applications (like cryptography), you really have to do much much better.

Comment: @vsoftco duh. rand() and random() are also pseudorandom, linear congruent generators.

Comment: @Rentsy I know, my point is that *the only REAL way to do this* is not to write your own PRNG, but to use a good one, like e.g. `std::mt19937`. Writing a good PRNG is extremely difficult, at least for the average programmer.

Comment: @vsoftco MT isn't cryptographically secure either. By "real," I didn't mean a search for the longest period, I meant a way that was 100% portable and consistent. That's why writing your own would make sense, especially educationally. Libraries... can't be guaranteed to behave as precisely as outputting the same stream of numbers with the same random seed.

Comment: Assuming RAND_MAX is 2^32-1. Then you have a slightly higher probability of rolling 1 or 2 than a 3, 4, 5 or 6. You may want to correct for this.

Comment: Or just ask Bruce Schneier. He can generate numbers so random that they surprise themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of several things has happened:

- The person who produced the list is assuming you will use a certain C++ standard library implementation + version, and you're expected to be using the same compiler/implementation + version, but you're not.  Your code is fine, but you need to talk to the person who made the list.
- The first 25 rolls are just a sample, and yours may/will differ. Your code is fine.
- You're using `rand` at different times: too often or too rarely.  If so, this is a bug in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You posted a singleTurn method, which takes as an argument holdNum. The result of your singleTurn method depends on your choice of holdNum.

You haven't told us how you choose holdNum, so I assume that's where the problem us.

But it might not be there.

It might be with the RNG itself.

Look, on my machine, I wrote the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int genRandInt (int minroll, int maxroll) {
    int randnum = minroll + (rand() % (maxroll - minroll + 1));
    return randnum;
}

int main()
{
    srand(333);
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        std::cout << " " << genRandInt(1,6);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It outputs this:

```
4 3 5 5 4 1 4 3 6 5 6 6 1 2 5 2 3 2 6 3 3 4 6 1
```

That's different from what you have, and what you are looking for.

Part of the issue is that srand is a black box. It could be 32-bit, or 16-bit. Futhermore, different implementations of linear congruent generators can use different numbers to make the answers.

Behind the scenes, the basic algorithm is this:

```
new_rand = mult * old_rand + add % mod
```

If mult and add are chosen correctly (in accordance with the Hull-Dobell theorem), you can get a cycle of at most 2^mod.

So what some good generators do is store the numbers are unsigned 32 or 64 bit integers, and wrap around automatically when they overflow, which saves on costly modulo arithmetic, and gets you the longest possible period.

You don't really know what rand() is doing, but I guarantee it's worse than random(), or a 64-bit RNG that you could write yourself.

Comment: holdNum should be irrelevant. The game simulates a single turn of a game called Pig. the Hold Number is user defined and where it stops once it has reached or passed that value. So for example, if you wanted to roll the dice until you hit or passed 21, it should keep rolling until it does or rolls a 1, which sets the score to 0 and ends the turn. With this seed, that means it should roll a 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4. At this point it has hit 23, which is greater than 21, so it should stop.